# Triple integral over the body $Q$ between two spheres

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

This is an exercise in using spherical coordinates.

Calculate the triple integral

$$J = \iiint_{Q}\ \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \,dy \,dz$$

where $Q$ is the body between the two spheres

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 $$ and

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 9 $$

The calculation is quite easy.

I am getting answer $8\pi$ but the answer given is $4\pi$.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Did you mean the volume between the 2 spheres?

Comment: @Staufenberg I mean $Q$ is the body that lies between the two spheres.

Comment: I also get $4\pi\cdot (3-1)=8\pi$

Comment: @Andrei OK, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the system of spherical coordinates (following a physicist notation) to obtain

$$
J = \int_1^3 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{r^2} \, r^2 \sin\theta \, \mathrm{d} \theta \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, \mathrm{d} r 
= 8\pi
$$

If they get $4\pi$, then the polar angle has only been integrated between $0$ and $\pi/2$, i.e.,  by considering the upper volume only.

Comment: So you are also getting $8\pi$? Just asking because you didn't show the intermediate calculations.

Comment: The integral is obvious

Comment: I know. Yes, it is. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @peter.petrov surprised that someone with over 12k reputations gets confused in this ;)

Comment: Well, it seems I got it right. But the answer in my book was confusing me so I just wanted to be sure. Sometimes it easily happens to miss a factor of two in a numerator or denominator.